# Azure Iothub's event hub compatible connection string

Tags: azure, templates, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to fetch the Event hub compatible connection string in ARM template and then pass it on to my HDInsight Cluster for further processing.

I am trying to create the event hub connectiong string of my choice, But the event hub name generated is not the same and consists of a guid whose source I am unable to track.

I need the to list and pass the event hub connection string to HDInsight script action within the template.

The endpoint part in the iothub resource is where I customize the event hub compatible connection string.

```
"resources": [
        {            
            "type": "Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs",
            "sku": {
                "name": "S1",
                "tier": "Standard",
                "capacity": 1
            },
            "name": "[variables('IotHub')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-02-03",
            "location": "southeastasia",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "ipFilterRules": [],
                "eventHubEndpoints": {
                    "events": {
                        "retentionTimeInDays": 4,
                        "partitionCount": 4,
                        "partitionIds": [
                            "0",
                            "1",
                            "2",
                            "3"
                        ],
                        "path": "[variables('IotHub')]",
                        "endpoint": "[concat('sb://', variables('IotHub'),'.servicebus.windows.net/')]"
                    }                 
                },
                "storageEndpoints": {
                    "$default": {
                        "sasTtlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                        "connectionString": "",
                        "containerName": ""
                    }
                },
                "enableFileUploadNotifications": false,
                "cloudToDevice": {
                    "maxDeliveryCount": 10,
                    "defaultTtlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                    "feedback": {
                        "lockDurationAsIso8601": "PT1M",
                        "ttlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                        "maxDeliveryCount": 10
                    }
                },
                "operationsMonitoringProperties": {
                    "events": {
                        "None": "None",
                        "Connections": "None",
                        "DeviceTelemetry": "None",
                        "C2DCommands": "None",
                        "DeviceIdentityOperations": "None",
                        "FileUploadOperations": "None"
                    }
                },
                "features": "None"
            },
            "resources": [],
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: IoT Hub and Event Hub are two different Azure services.  It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Azure's Iot Hub has a event hub compatible connection string available to be used with applications working with event hub conn. strings. I am trying to customize the created event hub connection string in the iothub service.

Comment: Did you create the connection string in ARM template with JSON type? Would you might show your code lines of creating the connection string in your JSON file?

Answer (score 4):

You can't set the values for the Event Hub-compatible name or Event Hub-compatible endpoint for an IoT Hub, these values are generated when the hub is created. However, you can access these values in an ARM template. The following snippet from the "outputs" section of a template that creates an IoT hub illustrates the syntax to use:

```
"outputs": {
  "eventHubCompatibleEndpoint": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IoTHubs',parameters('hubName'))).eventHubEndpoints.events.endpoint]"
  },
  "eventHubCompatibleName": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Devices/IoTHubs',parameters('hubName'))).eventHubEndpoints.events.path]"
  }
}
```

Comment: So, Yes I figured that part out but now what I am stuck at is that my what will be analogous to policy name in Azure iot hub. I am using the iothubowner policy.

Comment: The connection string for the Event Hubs-compatible endpoint looks like this:

"Endpoint={youreventhubcompatibleendpoint};EntityPath={youreventhubcompatiblename};SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={youriothubkey}"

Use any defined policy for the IoT hub, but remember that this is a read-only endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Dominic

Comment: Is there any documentation describing the object of 'eventHubEndpoints' and/or 'eventHubEndpoints.events'?